# ArrayList related method in a class not running in a program

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I have this program and class written:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dictionary {
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    ///////////////////////////////////// MAIN METHOD /////////////////////////////////////
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;

        Dictionary words = new Dictionary();

        // Add some words to it
        words.addWord("dog");
        words.addWord("cat");
        words.addWord("rat");
        words.addWord("ant");
        words.addWord("pig");
        words.addWord("goat");
        words.addWord("bear");

        // Print the list of words so you can see it
        // Note that the list of words is in sorted order.
        System.out.println(words.getWords());

        do {
            choice = menu();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: // Add
                    System.out.print("What word do you want to add? ");
                    String input = console.next();
                    System.out.println("Was the word added? " + words.addWord(input));
                    break;
                case 2: // Remove
                    System.out.print("What word do you want removed? ");
                    input = console.next();
                    System.out.println("Was the word removed? " + words.removeWord(input));
                    break;
                case 3: // Check to see if it is there
                    System.out.print("What word do you want check the location of? ");
                    input = console.next();
                    System.out.println("Was the word found in the ArrayList? " + words.isWord(input));
                    break;
                case 4: // Print
                    System.out.println(words);
                    break;
                case 5: // Find similar Words
                    System.out.print("What similarity do you want to look for? ");
                    input = console.next();
                    System.out.println("Here are the similar words: " + words.findWordsLike(input));
                    break;
                case 6: // Bye
                    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                    break;
                default: // huh?
                    break;
            }

        } while (choice != 6);
    }

    public static int menu() {
        int userChoice;

        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("  1.  Add a word");
        System.out.println("  2.  Remove a word");
        System.out.println("  3.  Check for the existence of a word");
        System.out.println("  4.  Print the Dictionary");
        System.out.println("  5.  Find words similar to another word");
        System.out.println("  6.  Quit");

        System.out.print("Choice>  ");
        userChoice = console.nextInt();

        return userChoice;
    }
//////////////////////////////////// Dictionary Class ////////////////////////////////        private ArrayList<String> myWords;
        private ArrayList<String> myWords;

        public Dictionary() { myWords = new ArrayList<String>(); }

        public ArrayList<String> getWords() { return myWords; }

        public void setMyWords(ArrayList<String> myWords) { this.myWords = myWords; }

        public boolean addWord(String word) {
            // Adds the variable word to myWords in the appropriate location
            // myWords is already sorted so you will need to find out where
            // word belongs and insert it there.
            // There is a method below name findWord that should
            // perform a binary search on the myWords array.
            // DO NOT RE-SORT THE ARRAY
            // Return value: true if the word was added
            //               false if not added (because already there or full)
            int index = findWord(word);
            if (index <= 0 && index != -1) {
                myWords.set((-(index + 1)), word);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean removeWord(String word) {
            // This method will find a word in myWords and remove it.  Keep
            // in mind that myWords is sorted and you must maintain that
            // sorted order.  You will have to find the word using a binary
            // search to receive full credit (Maybe make a method call?!)
            // DO NOT RE-SORT THE myWords ARRAY
            // Return Value: true if the word was remove
            //               false if the word was not remove (not found)
            int index;
            index = Collections.binarySearch(myWords, word);
            if (index > 0)  {
                myWords.remove(index);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isWord(String word) {
            // Determine if the word passed to the method is in myWords
            // Must use a binary search for full credit.
            // Return Value: true if the word is in myWords
            //               false if the word is not in myWords
            int index;
            Collections.sort(myWords);
            index = Collections.binarySearch(myWords, word);
            if (index < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<String> findWordsLike(String likeMe) {
            // Looks through the entire myWords array and any word that
            // contains likeMe should be added to the ArrayList.
            // Example: likeMe = do
            //          ArrayList could contain: do, dogma, dope, redo, todo
            ArrayList<String> similarWords = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < myWords.size(); i++) {
                if (myWords.get(i).contains(likeMe)) {
                    similarWords.add(myWords.get(i));
                }
            }
            return similarWords;
        }

        private int findWord(String word) {
            // Performs a binary search on myWords to determine if word is in myWords
            // Return Value: location of word or the 2's complement of where it belongs
            // Keep in mind myWords is not full
            int low = 0;
            int high = myWords.size() - 1;

            while(high >= low) {
                int middle = (low + high) / 2;
                if (myWords.get(middle) == word) {
                    return middle;
                }
                if (!myWords.get(middle).equals(word)) {
                    if (middle < myWords.indexOf(word)) {
                        low = middle+ 1;
                    } else if (middle > myWords.indexOf(word)) {
                        high = middle - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

The comments in the Dictionary class describe what each method is supposed to do. My problem is with the addWord method because when I run the program, I get an empty ArrayList and nothing has been added to it. I can figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're getting? What specifically are you doing that triggers the error? What specific error are you getting? And what have you done so far to try to identify the problem?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I run the program and instead of printing the ArrayList in the main method at System.out.println(words.getWords()); , I get this: [] with nothing in the ArrayList. This leads me to believe that the AddWord method in my Dictionary class is the problem but I can't see what's wrong with it because everything seems like it should run properly. I don't understand why my program isn't adding the words to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addWord` method replace

```
int index = findWord(word);
if (index <= 0 && index != -1) {
    myWords.set((-(index + 1)), word);
```

with

```
int index = myWords.indexOf(word);
if (index == -1){
    myWords.add(word);
```

and it will work.